# SAS ODS Sandwich in PROC ARIMA with BY statement generate strange results

Tags: sas, export-to-excel, ods

I'm trying to export a bunch of stationarity tests to both HTML and Excel.  With `PROC ARIMA` I'm getting strange behaviour when I try to wrap each part in an "ODS Sandwich".  It appears this is due to using the `BY var` command in `PROC ARIMA`.  When `BY` is not used I get the expected/desired `ODS` output.

When I `CLOSE` an `ODS` "sandwich" the preceeding `ARIMA` output is dropped from the file I try to send it to.  It is instead saved in the subsequent `ODS` destination that I open.  The result is the final `ODS` `ARIMA` output is lost and each file is incorrectly named and located.

The dataset `abc` is produced at the bottom.  Here is the reproducible commands that are failing for me.

```
/*  =========================================== */
/*          PROC ARIMA for Stationarity
                  LEVELS                        */
/*  =========================================== */

ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;

%let pt    = 1;
%let ARpt1 = LEVELS;
ODS graphics on / reset= INDEX imagename="&ARpt1.";

filename X_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir.ARIMA_ADF_&ARpt1..xlsx" ;
filename H_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir.ARIMA_ADF_&ARpt1..html" ;
filename g_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir." ;

ods html  (id=&pt.) file= H_ADF&pt.    gpath = g_ADF&pt.;
ods EXCEL (id=&pt.) file = X_ADF&pt.  
    options(SHEET_INTERVAL="NONE"   /* All tables in one sheet*/
            SHEET_NAME ="LEVELS"
            EMBEDDED_TITLES="YES");

PROC ARIMA data= abc;
    by grp;
 TITLE "ARIMA IDENTIFY - U in levels";

    identify var=  testvar
    stationarity = (adf=(3));
    ods html (id=&pt.)  select StationarityTests SeriesCorrPanel;
    ods EXCEL (id=&pt.) select StationarityTests ;
RUN;

/************************************
   If I include the CLOSE here 
    then the ODS files declared above are empty

*********************************/
ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;


/*  =========================================== */
/*          PROC ARIMA for Stationarity
                    Differences                 */
/*  =========================================== */
%let pt    = 2;
%let ARpt2 = YonY_diff;

ODS graphics on / reset= INDEX imagename="&ARpt2.";

filename X_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir.ARIMA_ADF_&ARpt2..xlsx" ;
filename H_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir.ARIMA_ADF_&ARpt2..html" ;
filename g_ADF&pt. "&outDir.&ARIMAdir." ;

ods html  (id=&pt.) file = H_ADF&pt.   gpath = g_ADF&pt.;
ods EXCEL (id=&pt.) file = X_ADF&pt.  
        options(SHEET_INTERVAL="NONE"    /* All tables in one sheet*/
                SHEET_NAME ="Lvl Diff"
                EMBEDDED_TITLES="YES");/* Title Put in EXCEL doc */ 

PROC ARIMA data= abc;
    by grp;
    TITLE "ARIMA IDENTIFY - First Differences by City";

    identify var= testvar(1)    stationarity = (adf=(3));
    ods html  (id=&pt.)         select StationarityTests SeriesCorrPanel;
    ods EXCEL (id=&pt.)         select StationarityTests ;
 RUN;

/************************************
   If I include the CLOSE here 
    then the ODS files (html and excel) declared here
   are filled with the data from the FIRST proc arima 
*********************************/
ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
```

Can anyone tell if its a problem with my code, or a particular issue with `ARIMA`?

**** **DATA SET abc CREATED HERE** ****

```
data a;
 u1 = 0.9; a1 = 0;
 do i = -50 to 100;
    a = rannor( 32565 );
    u = u1 + a - .8 * a1;
    if i > 0 then output;
    a1 = a;
    u1 = u;
 grp = "a";
end;
run;
data b;
 u1 = -0.5; a1 = 0;
    do i = -50 to 100;
       a = rannor( 876196 );
       u = u1 + a - .8 * a1;
       if i > 0 then output;
       a1 = a;
       u1 = u;
     grp = "b";
    end;
run;
data c;
     u1 = 5; a1 = 0.1;
     do i = -50 to 100;
        a = rannor( 876196 );
        u = u1 + a - .8 * a1;
        if i > 0 then output;
        a1 = a;
        u1 = u;
     grp = "c";
    end;
run;
data abc;
   merge a b c;
by grp;
run;
```

Comment: I wonder if you have a problem with the fact that `PROC ARIMA` is interactive (run-group) and expects a `QUIT;`, though I don't see an obvious connection (RUN should cause the output object to be created, and in a quick test it seems like it behaves how I expect it and how your program expects it).  I would recommend creating a simpler example - one that uses simulatable data so we can see it on our side - and replicate the issue that way.

Comment: You might use http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_arima_sect055.htm as your base example, as it's readily available for us to use.  That's what I used in my example test, which produced output like you would expect.

Comment: Thanks @Joe - that helped me isolate the issue to the `BY` statement.  The problem only seems to arise when I'm doing `ARIMA` by group.  I've updated the question in this regard and included some reproducible data adapted from that example test.

Comment: Try Move the ODS Select to before the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed the position of `QUIT;` when by-group processing is used. That is because the `RUN;` doesn't do anything when you are using by-group processing (as SAS would prefer to know all of the things you want to do for each BY-group prior to doing any of them).  So your `ODS HTML CLOSE;` and such don't execute when you think they do.

Here's a token example that shows this problem.  Try running without the comment on QUIT; and then with it, see the difference.

```
   title1 'Simulated IMA(1,1) Series';
   data a;
     dummy=1;
     u1 = 0.9; a1 = 0;
     do i = -50 to 100;
        a = rannor( 32565 );
        u= u1 + a - .8 * a1;
        if i > 0 then output;
        a1 = a;
        u1 = u;
     end;
   run; 


   ods html3 file="c:\temp\test.html";
   ods excel file="c:\temp\test.xlsx";
   proc arima data=a;
     by dummy;
     identify var=u;
     ods html3 select DescStats;
     ods excel select  SeriesCorrPanel;
     run;
     *quit;
  ods html3 close;
  ods excel close;

  *Here I put them out to a different file to make more obvious what is happening;
  ods html3 file="c:\temp\test1.html";
  ods excel file="c:\temp\test1.xlsx";
  proc arima data=a;
    by dummy;
     ods html3 select DescStats;
     ods excel select  SeriesCorrPanel;
     identify var=u(1);
     run;
    *quit;
  ods html3 close;
  ods excel close;
quit;
```

Comment: Ah I see.  Using `quit;` indeed solves the problem.  Trying to undertand this better, I came across your excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764328/quit-vs-run-statements-in-sas, which is useful in general and for this issue in particular.  Thanks again!